# Translating a sin curve into one that lingers on its maximums longer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

The goal is to create an animation curve mathematically that moves like a sin curve but holds at the extremes. I would also love to be able to parameterize it.

[image: Image showing desired graph behavior]
In the graph note how the domain spent at either 1 or -1 increases while the function still transitions smoothly in and out of these extremes.

Thus far I have graphs of the following forms with no luck

```
sin(x)*sin(x)^a
sin(x)^a // This sort of works when a is [0, 1] however I do not like that the derivative appears infinite when y =0
sin(sin(x))
sin(x)+sin(x+a)
```

I really have not seen a formula that can do this. Is it even possible to translate a regular sine curve into one that lingers at its extremes?

A function that is not even technically sinusoidal would be ok so long as it is periodic or can be made periodic by modulo-ing x.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Cosine'-esque function with flat peaks and valleys](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100655/cosine-esque-function-with-flat-peaks-and-valleys). The derivative is very steep around $x = \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3 \pi}{2} \cdots$ but is not actually infinite: this is a natural consequence of flattening the curve.

Comment: A square wave is the limit of a certain infinite sum of sine waves (its Fourier series), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave.  However, sine waves are slow to compute and the partial sums of the square wave series have undesirable overshoots near the vertical part.  So usually a polynomial approximation is preferable, like $1-x^{2n}$ from about -1 to 1 and $(x-a)^{2n}$ (with $a$ chosen so they line up) from about 1 to 3, and repeat it.  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ehyhl6lphd

Answer (score 2):

Try:

$$f(x) = \frac{\vert\sin x\vert^{2-p}}{\sin x}$$

If $p=0$, you have a regular sine curve:
[image]
When $p$ goes from $0$ to $1$, the function smoothly goes between the extremes. $p = \frac{1}{2}$:
[image]
Finally, as $p$ goes to $1$ you get the square wave.
[image]
The function can also be written as:

$$f(x) = \text{sgn}(\sin x)\cdot\vert\sin x\vert^{1-p}$$

This might give some more intuition as to why it works. For more, see [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6ntscroedg).